# Bootstrap 5.2.3 modal - HTML form causes blank screen

Tags: bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I am having an issue with form within a modal. I can have to time input elements, no more nor can I have any date elements or the screen will go blank instead of showing the modal.

Here the working version of the modal with the two time inputs

```html
<div class="hidden modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body" id="bookingIdText">

            </div>
            <form action="myBookingBackend.php" method='post'>
                <div>
                    <label for="timeStart">Time Start</label> 
                    <input type="time" name="timeStart" id="timeStart">

                    <label for="timeEnd">Time End</label> 
                    <input type="time" name="timeEnd" id="timeEnd">

                    <input type="hidden" name="bookingIdHidden" id="bookingIdHidden" value="">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primasry">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is an image to show you it working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKUjG.png)

And here is a non-functioning version of my modal. Note: the new time input is a direct copy and past of the previous time input with name and id changed so in theory there should be no issue.

```html
<div class="hidden modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body" id="bookingIdText">

            </div>
            <form action="myBookingBackend.php" method='post'>
                <div>
                    <label for="timeStart">Time Start</label> 
                    <input type="time" name="timeStart" id="timeStart">

                    <label for="timeEnd">Time End</label> 
                    <input type="time" name="timeEnd" id="timeEnd">

                    <label for="timeEnd1">Time End</label> 
                    <input type="time" name="timeEnd1" id="timeEnd1">

                    <input type="hidden" name="bookingIdHidden" id="bookingIdHidden" value="">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primasry">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[and... not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqeQy.png)

I have struggle with this issue for a bit and cannot work it out nor can I find anything online regarding it.

Here is my version of bootstrap I am using

````html
```     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
````

I have the same issue when attempting to use the `<select>` and `<option>` tags to create a dropdown box so I tried out these:

```html
       <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

No luck

I thought I may add, this modal uses jQuery to set the value of the hidden element

Just in case this is the cause of my troubles, here is the jQuery function

```js
function takeId(newButtonId){
    
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    try {
        $('#bookingIdHidden').attr('value', newButtonId);

    } catch(err) {
        alert(err); 
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' name='edit' value='Edit' onclick=takeId($newButtonId) id='1' </button>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You should throw your most current code into a jsfiddle or something.

Comment: Have inserted all code into the live snippets now

Answer (score 0):

I think that more context might be needed.

Are you trying to stay on the page after submitting the form?

It looks like you're submitting to myBookingBackend.php. When I pasted your example into a jsfiddle, the form submitted as expected. Did you redirect after performing your business logic in myBookingBackend.php?

If you're trying to submit the form and stay on the page, then you'll need to use an ajax request. Since you're using jQuery already, check out the docs on the [ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). You can also use the [post method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), and [get method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) which are just a little less verbose.

I've got the modal working without clearing the page in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w4hxrzjd/1/).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>


<div class="hidden modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body" id="bookingIdText">


              <form action="https://mocki.io/v1/63dd1e5a-95a4-4a6c-b179-54805e8d8236" method='post'>
                  <div>
                      <label for="timeStart">Time Start</label> 
                      <input type="time" name="timeStart" id="timeStart">

                      <label for="timeEnd">Time End</label> 
                      <input type="time" name="timeEnd" id="timeEnd">

                      <input type="hidden" name="bookingIdHidden" id="bookingIdHidden" value="">
                  </div>

                  <!--<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>-->
                  <button type="button" onclick="someFunction()" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">The old button did a server side form submission (not ajax) so the page will get redirect to myBookingBackend.php, which is expected. You could do a client side request and update the page like this instead if that's what you're looking for.</button>
              </form>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function someFunction() {
    alert("The page won't be cleared, because you won't be going anywhere.");
  // you can get the form info
  var bookingEndpoint = document.querySelector("#myModal form").action
  // then do your ajax request
  $.get(bookingEndpoint, function(data) {
    console.log("Booking endpoint was hit.")
})
  .done(function(data) {
        console.log("Data returned by the request")
        console.log(data)
      document.querySelector("#myModal form").innerHTML = "Thanks! You're booking was successful.";
  })
  .fail(function() {
      document.querySelector("#myModal form").innerHTML = "Thanks! You're booking was successful.";
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log("Ajax request has completed.")
  });

}
</script>
```